# Trouble installing nmea_navsat_driver package?

Tags: rospy, ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm currently trying to set up a GPS receiver and base station my boss purchased to work in ROS. It is a trimble Ag GPS 542 GNSS receiver ( http://ssmgps.com/pdf/AGPB_AgGPS542_B... ). It looks like the deivce can work in NMEA-0183 sentences, and thus that it should be compatible with the nmea_navsat_driver ROS package, found here: http://wiki.ros.org/nmea_navsat_driver , but I am encountering some installation issues.

I have extracted the package into my catkin_ws/src directory using

```
 git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver
```

Then I run catkin_make, and get the following response:

CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a configuration file for package roslint.

Set roslint_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
roslint.  The file will have one of the following names:

roslintConfig.cmake
roslint-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
nmea_navsat_driver/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)

CMake Error at nmea_navsat_driver/CMakeLists.txt:23 (roslint_python):
Unknown CMake command "roslint_python".

I don't know what roslint_DIR is, and can't find anything about it online, but I did try searching my computer for both roslintConfig.cmake and roslint-config.cmake (no results for either).  Anyone know what could be going wrong/how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190264/trouble-installing-nmea_navsat_driver-package?/) by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-14**:
I'm not sure if I modified everything I should have from your example, but I tried

rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

And it told me "ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
toro: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [ncurses++]" Ncurses is something I'm using in another executable in the same project (that I don't care about anymore).  I tried commenting out the CMakeLists reference to that executable, but it didn't change the error.

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2014-08-14**:
another option is to create another worskpace and clone only the gps driver there. Can you try that?

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-14**:
Alright, made a catkin_ws2 right next to the first one (had to check out the ros tutorials again).  Then I added the path to my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, cloned  it into the src directory, and catkin_made.  Unfortunately, I get exactly the same error.

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-14**:
Actually I get what you mean now.  I ran the rosdep install line in my catkin_ws2 and it worked.  Now catkin_make builds successfully and I can run the executable!  So what exactly did that line do? I don't understand the --from-paths src and --ignore-src parts.

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2014-08-15**:
you can read what they mean in the [installation guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source#Building_the_catkin_Packages) from source for indigo (section 2.1.2).

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-19**:
Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

did you tried checking the dependencies before catkin_make? for example,

`rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y`

another option is to create another worskpace and clone only the gps driver there.

EDIT: Added second part from the comments.

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mysteriousmonkey29](https://answers.ros.org/users/9531/mysteriousmonkey29/) on 2014-08-19**:
Initialized a second catkin_ws, git cloned the package into the src directory, and ran the suggested line in it:
rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src --rosdistro hydro -y

Then catkin built and the installation is complete.